# Computing homography of parallel plane

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

I'm using OpenCV to compute the homography projection from one plane, let's say Plane1 to a another plane, called CenitalView.

The homography matrix (H1) is calculated by selecting some points in both Plane1 and CenitalView.

Is it possible, just by having this information, to obtain a second homography matrix (H2) which will relate a parallel plane to Plane1 and the same CenitalView?

Resuming:

Plane 1 -> H1 -> CenitalView
Plane 2 (// Plane1) -> H2? -> CenitalView

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you know the homography between plane1 and plane2.

Plane 1 -> H1 -> CenitalView

If Plane 1 -> HP -> Plane 2 then
Plane 2 -> HP^-1 * H1 -> CenitalView

So just knowing that Plane 1 and Plane 2 are parallel isn't enough, afaik.

Comment: Thanks! That could be a way.

Comment: Hi Micka, could you please kindly give me any clues on how to calculate the homography between Plane 1 and Plane 2 if I know that they are parallel and the real world distance between them, and also the calibration parameters of camera? Thanks.

Comment: @Jackypengyu you can create 3D planes from your known parameters. Then shoot a eay from your camera center through any pixel. This ray will hit plane1 and plane2 in some coordinates. Do this for 4 points and you should be able to compute a homography between those planes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the the original point (0, 0) and the x- and y- axises in Plane2. Otherewise you cannot.

Suppose you rotate plane2 around the normal verctor of Plane2, and you get Plane3, Plane4, ....

All these planes are parallel planes of Plane1. Obviously they have different homography matrixes regarding Cenital View.

Comment: Both Plane1 and Plane2 will only be different in z-axis. There will just be a distance d between planes. That's why I was asking if ithere is any relation between these two matrices as both relate parallel planes with respect to CenitalView plane

Comment: known distance d? And are the camera intrinsics known?

Comment: Both d and camera intrinsic are known yes.